# Flutter Image Picker not working on android

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-image-picker

I'm having a problem whenever I load an image on the Android Emulator/Physical Device, in iOS works fine.

These are the two main methods I'm using, they are in the class Photo Repository

```
void savePhoto(XFile imageFile) async {
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = "${directory.path}/${imageFile.name}";
    imageFile.saveTo(path);
    persistenceController.setProfilePic(path);
    firestoreRepository.uploadImageToFirestore(File(imageFile.path));
  }

 Future<XFile?> takePhoto(ImageSource source) async {
    final pickedFile = await imagePicker.pickImage(
      source: source,
      maxHeight: 680,
      maxWidth: 970,
    );

    return pickedFile;
  }
```

This is the way I'm picking the photos

```
TextButton.icon(
                onPressed: () async {
                  pickedFile = await photoRepository.takePhoto(ImageSource.camera);
                  setState(() {
                    _imagePath = pickedFile!.path;
                    print(_imagePath);
                    _imageFile = pickedFile!;
                  });
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.camera),
                label: const Text('Cámara'),
              ),
              TextButton.icon(
                onPressed: () async {
                  pickedFile = await photoRepository.takePhoto(ImageSource.gallery);
                  setState(() {
                    _imagePath = pickedFile!.path;
                    print(_imagePath);
                    _imageFile = pickedFile!;
                  });
                },
```

The photo path is saved in the sharedPreferences using this method

```
 Future<void> setProfilePic(String imageName) async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString('profilePic', imageName);
  }
```

Finally this is the stack trace

[image]

The thing is that it works perfectly on iOS, but it doesn't work on Android

I've haven't really tried anything as I'm not sure how to proceed, it shouldn't fail like that

Comment: Where are you using the path that gets saved to sharedPreferences? Can you share that code?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add permission requests in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

> android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however at the end turns out I had to use FileImage() instead of AssetImage